# Efficiently looping a 2-for

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, for-loop

There is a 1:1 relationship between `user` & `employee`, I **must** to get the data separately so I have to find the best way to assign the employee to the corresponding user. For that, I have this 2-`foreach` function (which I realized is 96% slower than a `for`)

I'm trying to find a better way to represent this. The `ids` variable contains a list of user's id. If the id matches, add the `employee` to the `user`.

```java
this.employeeService.query({'userId.in': ids}).subscribe(employeeData => {
    employeeData.body.forEach(employee => {
        this.users.forEach(user => {
            if (user.id === employee.userId) {
                user.employee = employee;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look for things efficiently, it's better to use a HashMap like structure.
In JavaScript, you can use a simple object.
Create a UserMap that holds the relation from userid to employee

```
let UserMap= {}
employees.forEach( employee =>UserMap[employee.userId]= employee)
```

Now you can:

```
users.forEach( user=> user.employee = UserMap[user.id])
```

The nested loop now become 2 separate for-loop which will be much more efficient.